# Greenlet installation fails with `OSError`

Tags: python, tensorflow, hyperparameters, optuna, greenlets

I try to install the `optuna` package into a TensorFlow `tensorflow:2.11.1-gpu` image.
However, it failed with

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/include/python3.8/greenlet'
```

Installing other versions of `optuna`/`greenlet` does not help.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around the issue and trying to install `greenlet` separately, installing different versions of `optuna` (<3.0.0 at the time of writing), I switched the base image from `tensorflow:2.11.1-gpu` to `tensorflow:2.13.0-gpu`.

Now, the installation is successful.